Is this graph problem NP-hard?
Given a bipartite graph G with bipartition $G = A \cup B$, and weights $w(v)$ for nodes of G such that $w(v)>0$ for $v \in A$ and $w(v)<0$ for $v \in B$. Let $V(G) = \{ v_1,v_2,..,v_n \}$. Call an ordering  $v_1,v_2,.., v_n$ permissible if for each $ v_i \in B $, all its neighbours in $A$ appear before it, that is, in $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_{i-1}$.
The weight of a permissible ordering is the maximum compound weight found along the way: $max_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^j w(v_i))$. Find a permissible ordering with minimal weight.
Alternate phrasing: Suppose you had a set of keys A and a set of chests B and each chest $b \in B$ requires a certain subset $A_b \subset A$ to open. Each key has a cost and each chest has some money. Find the order of keys to purchase that minimizes the amount of money you need at the beginning.

I've gone in and fixed some details, but your main criterion is unclear, so I've left it alone. It looks like you don't want the maximum of $ \sum_{i=1}^j w(v_i)$ for all $j$, but the sum of all that are positive: $\sum_{j=1}^n \max(0,\sum_{i=1}^j w(v_i))$.

@reinierpost I think it was clear. The measure is $\max_j \sum_i^j w(v_i)$. You want to find a permissible ordering that minimizes that maximum.

@reinierpost ... That is, you make money from "visiting" B, and pay to visit A.

Oh ... yes, we don't need to sum twice. Fixed, thanks.

Not an answer; too long for a comment.
I think that you should stop looking at this as a graph problem and rather model it with weighted set systems (or hypergraphs). You also only need to order $A$, since you can safely assume that every $b \in B$ comes as early as possible.
In addition, you can probably binary search (or linear search) the max value, so you may assume that you know $t \in \mathbb Z_+$.
Now you define the problem as vertices ($A$) and hyperedges ($B$). You have to delete all vertices, and the cost of deleting a vertex $v$ is $w(v) > 0$. When all vertices in a hyperedge is deleted, you get ("pay") the value of the edge $w(v) < 0$.
Ie, you are only allowed to delete empty hyperedges, and then you get its value. You have to delete all vertices while never exceeding the threshold $t$.
Since we know $t$, if any hyperedge has the property that the sum of the vertices is lower than both $t$ and the hyperedge value, you may safely delete all vertices and the hyperedge.
I have no idea whether the problem is NP-hard or not, but currently I wouldn't be surprised either way. (Leaning towards hardness.)

meanwhile my intuition was to order $B$, with all $A$s coming as late as possible...

@NooneAtAll3 yes, exactly. Those are equivalent. It never makes sense to delete a vertex in $A$ before you absolutely need to, i.e. in order to delete a hyperedge (of $B$).
